# Can we say that $\lim_{n \to \infty}n \mathbb{1}_{f(x) \geq n}=0$ when f is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Can we say that $\lim_{n \to \infty}n \mathbb{1}_{f(x) \geq n}=0$ when f is integrable?
I think yes since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{1}_{f(x) \geq n}=0$ a.s and multiplying $0$ by any number and even in the limit should give me $0$.

Even though I am not convinced what I wrote is true but I read somewhere in a book(maybe Rudin) that we assume that $0. \infty=0$

Comment: In general, if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{f_n(x)} = 0$ a.s., we cannot conclude that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{nf_n(x)} = 0$. In this case, however, we can (assuming you can show that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\mathbb{1}_{f(x)\ge n}} = 0$ a.s.), since indicator functions can only take on the values $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Well if f is integrable (wrt to say some positive measure ) then its true almost surely which is given in the question. And its just a function not a sequence of functions. Right?

Comment: This seems to mix two contexts. Let $f_n(x)=n\mathbf 1_{f(x)\geqslant n}$. Then, first, $f_n(x)\to0$ when $n\to\infty$, for every $x$ such that $f(x)$ is finite. This is not related to the integrability of $f$. Second, if $f$ is $\mu$-integrable, then $\int f_nd\mu\to0$.

Comment: The argument in Rudin might be that if $x_n=0$ for every $n$ large enough then indeed $x_ny_n\to0$ for every other sequence $(y_n)$.

Comment: @Did what I meant is that when f is integrable  then $f< \infty$ a.s then $f_{n}(x) \to 0 $a.s follows directly from your argument . Doesn't it ?

Comment: As I said, to mention the integrability in this context is misleading. The condition to ensure that $f_n\to0$ almost everywhere is that $f$ is finite almost everywhere.

Comment: Did I am sorry and a little confused. i agree that $f$ finite almost everywhere is all that is needed to ensure $f_n \to 0$ but I do not understand why you say that integrability in this context is misleading? Doesnt integrability of f imply that its finite everywhere.I mean if the question gives me this condition, I can use it to say that f(x) is finite almost everywhere and conclude that $f_n \to 0$

Comment: I think because it's a bit like arguing: Show that you can travel one mile within an hour if you use a Ferrari. Yes, you can - but every healthy pedestrian can do, too. Logically, you're absolutely right. Nevertheless, integrability points in a direction which is indeed misleading since it's way too strong as a condition.

Comment: @BerndH  thank you very much